# How to compare the growth rate between $\ln\ln n$ and $2^{lg^* n}$

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

Simple question, I've read in the answer sheet that the growth rate of  $\ln\ln n$  is bigger than $2^{lg^* n}$, but I can't figure out how to prove it. Could someone help me out pls?

P.S. lg* is the iterative logarithm often used in algorithmic analysis.

Comment: What do you mean by $2^{lg^* n}$?

Comment: $2^{\text{lg}(n)}=n$ which grows faster than $\text{ln(ln}(n))$ (if by lg(n) you mean the logarithm with base 2). To prove it, use derivatives or something.

Comment: $lg^* n$ is an iterated logarithm it's not a typo.

Comment: It's clear from the comments that the notation is unclear. Please edit your question to explain the notation used.

Answer (score 1):

The given functions are: **ln ln *n*** and $\;\mathbf2^\mathbf{lg^*n}$.

Now, if we take ***log*** on both sides, then **ln ln *n*** becomes **lg ln ln *n***, and $\;\mathbf2^\mathbf{lg^*n}$ becomes **lg*n**.

Therefore, we have the asymptotic bound: **lg ln ln *n*** = $\boldsymbol\omega\pmb(lg^\boldsymbol*n\pmb)$. Which is, **ln ln *n*** = $\boldsymbol\omega\pmb(2^{lg^\boldsymbol*n}\pmb)$.

Which means, that the function **ln ln *n*** grows at a much faster rate than the function$\;\mathbf2^\mathbf{lg^*n}$ as the value of n approaches infinity.